# Cannot install deb command in Debian Docker image

Tags: debian, docker

I'm trying to install a deb package in a Docker image.

I based my Dockerfile on [continuumio/miniconda3](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/miniconda3) that's a Python/Debian image.

This works fine in Debian 9 but not when I try to build my Docker image. The problem that I have is that the `deb` command is not in Debian, and I cannot find a way to install it in the image. Any ideas how to install the `deb` command or another way to run that statement?

These are the [commands](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-ax-mariadb-columnstore-from-the-package-repositories-12x/#debian-9):

```
RUN apt-get -y install apt-transport-https dirmngr
RUN deb https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-columnstore-tools/latest/repo/debian9 stretch main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deb` is not a command.

The line belongs in a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

Just as explained in the documentation you linked.

Comment: so after I add the line to the file I have to run another command?

Comment: Read the instructions. They explain it step by step.